# Grid pick the level up in window

Tags: extjs, grid

Hello i am have window with grid, but grid is under all panels, how i am can pick up grid

```
 {
                xtype: 'bookgrid',
                name: 'bookgrid_name',
                autoHeight: true,
                viewConfig: {
                    plugins: {
                        ptype: 'gridviewdragdrop',
                        dragGroup: 'resourcesDDGroup'
                    },
                    listeners: {
                    },
                    copy: true
                }
            }
```

[image]

Comment: ¿ExtJS 5? or which version

Answer (score 0):

You have two options to use on your controller:

**down** http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.dom.Element-method-down

```
var me = this.getView();
me.down('bookgrid[name="bookgrid_name"]);
```

**lookupReference** http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.container.Container-method-lookupReference

```
{
                xtype: 'bookgrid',
                name: 'bookgrid_name',
                reference: 'myBookGrid',
                autoHeight: true,
                viewConfig: {
                    plugins: {
                        ptype: 'gridviewdragdrop',
                        dragGroup: 'resourcesDDGroup'
                    },
                    listeners: {
                    },
                    copy: true
                }
            }
```

in your controller --> `var grid = this.lookupReference('myBookGrid');`